# how to amend a batch script to include unzip of files after renaming

Tags: batch-file

How can I amend the below batch script, to unzip all files in the folder after renaming is done, and move the zip file to another folder.

```
@echo off

set "dir=D:\temp\"
set "pfx=A001_"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r "%dir%" %%A in (*.txt.GZ) do (
    set "xml=%%~nA"
    if not "!txt:~0,13!"=="%pfx%" ren "%%A" "%pfx%%%~nxA"
)

for %%a in (*.GZ) do (
    Call :UnZipFile "D:\temp\%%~na\" "D:\temp\oldfiles\%%~nxa"
)

pause
```

Comment: I would suggest that `txt` in the above code should read as `xml`; or vice versa. Additionally this site isn't here to write your code for you, or step by step tell you what to write yourself. That would be a direct or indirect code request, which is off topic here. This site is supposed to help you with a fix for a specific issue with your code, (which has been written to perform the task it was intended to perform). Please use the search facility and relevant help information, to complete your code, then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60038902/edit) accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without actually writing the code for you, I can tell you that 7-Zip has a command line version available, and it is marvelous. From their download page, just make sure to download the package named "7-Zip Extra: standalone console version, 7z DLL, Plugin for Far Manager".

The console version is named "7za.exe". If you run it with no parameters, it shows a whole list of options you can use with it.